# How do we get a calculated range of cells for worksheet.get_Range?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am creating an Excel file using C# and the Excel contents are different each time. I want to specify a variable in the function worksheet.get_Range instead of the regular b4 or e4.

If I have not been able to make myself clear, I am trying to do something like this:

```
int temp= numberofiterations * 5;

worksheet.get_Range("A1", A1+temp );
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Where do you want to end up? `A6`? `F1`? Anywhere else? What is `A1+temp` supposed to do?

Comment: That is the whole point.It will end up at a different location each time depending on the value of the variable "numberofiterations"

Comment: So where? What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: Okay, so this program is supposed to create an excel for a release and the release is chosen through a dropdown.Each release has different number of iterations so the number of cells in the excel created will be different each time.Could I get my point across ?